# how to join related country and city google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a problem with joining two columns based on related city and country names in google sheets or in excel maybe (if that helps)

I have two columns like this
[image: columns]

`Columns O` is the name of the cities and `column P` is the country names

I want to join the cities to the related countries and add a character in between like `|` separated by comma's

so the result would be like `Buenos Aires | Argentina, Lima | Peru,  .....` in the corresponding rows

Example: [Google Sheets Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L9Jo9IwrSa8Jn3q0Wu_P9otMMA2m2PZa-JDlsaRwfX0/edit?usp=sharing)

how am I able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each column O and P (excluding row 1)

1. Join everything in the column using a comma, as that's the delimiter that's already present. (Use a filter to exclude blanks.) `JOIN(",", FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O))))`
2. Split the join so that every value is in its own cell. `SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))), ",", FALSE)`
3. Transpose the output for easier manipulation. (Operations are typically easier on columns than rows.) `TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))), ",", FALSE))`
4. Trim each cell to get rid of spaces on either side of the values. `ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))), ",", FALSE))))`
5. Get rid of duplicate values. `UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))), ",", FALSE)))))`

Then you can join the two using the template `JOIN(", ", ARRAYFORMULA("city"&" | "&"country"))`. Ultimately, this formula should give you what you want.

```
=JOIN(", ",
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))), ",", FALSE)))))
    &" | "&
    UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(P2:P, NOT(ISBLANK(P2:P)))), ",", FALSE)))))
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the tip but I think that can't be my the solution because its a dataset with roughly 87k rows and each row has other information columns too.... this is what I have  [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L9Jo9IwrSa8Jn3q0Wu_P9otMMA2m2PZa-JDlsaRwfX0/edit?usp=sharing) it has writing privileges